# Why isn't the following scope variable becoming undefined inside my directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to get the value of `panodatas` (define as `$scope.panodatas` in my controller) and use it in the `link` section of my directive:

**JS:**

```
scope: {
        floorplan: "@",
        points: "=",
        panodatas: "=",
        getPanos: "&"
      },
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        console.log(scope.panodatas)
        scope.getPanos().then(function() {
          console.log(scope.panodatas)
```

**HTML:**

```
  <pre>{{panodatas | json}}</pre>
  <panodata-editor
    floorplan="http://ac-x69r2ohx.clouddn.com/3171600a0de6f740c152.jpg"
    points="points"
    panodatas="panodatas"
    get-panos="getPanos()"
  >
  </panodata-editor>
```

But it doesn't work, both `console.log(scope.panodatas)` return `undefined`. Why is this? How can I get the value of `$scope.panodatas` and use it in `link: function() {...}`?

*Note:*

`<pre>{{panodatas | json}}</pre>` is working, so `panodatas` does have the value:

```
[
  {
    "objectId": "56a74de0d342d30054170231",
    "index": 2,
    "x": 200,
    "y": 200,
    "createdAt": "2016-01-26T10:43:44.482Z"
  },
  {
    ...
  },
  ...
```

**EDIT:**

This is how `panodatas` is being defined in my controller:

```
var all = function() { return $q.all([serviceUpload.getAllBuilding(isUpdated)]) }

$scope.getPanos = function() {
  return all().then(function(value) {
    $scope.buildingTree = JSON.parse(value)
    $scope.panoId = $routeParams.panoId
    $scope.pano = _($scope.buildingTree).chain().
    pluck('pano').
      flatten().
      findWhere({objectId: $scope.panoId}).
      value()
    $scope.panodatas = $scope.pano.panoData
  }, function(reason) {
    $scope.result = reason
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because when the linker is run is before the promise returns with panodatas.

Comment: Oh, I thought this part `scope.getPanos().then(function() {` waited for the promise to be done. How can I get the value of $scope.panodatas and use it inside `link: function() {}` then?

Comment: No, javascript never works synchronously. It would be awful if it did.  Well if you can bind it just fine in the directive. When ever getPanos resolves the directive will be updated (yay two way binding!).  You could create a watch in the directive.